# Which is more efficient of checking for files, Firebase Storage exists check vs Firebase Database get

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have been unable to find any documentation that discusses best practices when it comes to managing images using Firebase.

I am considering whether or not to add the filenames of uploaded images into the database or not.

If they're in the database then I can make one db `get` request to get the list of existing images. These would be put into the database on fileUploaded events and deleted from the database on delete.

Is it better for me to just do a few file exists requests directly on the Storage and not have the db overhead, for instance (pseudo code);

```
if ( gcs.exists('/storage_path/favicon.png') ) {
...
}

if ( gcs.exists('/storage_path/favicon-32x32.png') ) {
...
}
```

Or is it better to store those images filenames in the database, assume they exist, and pull them out in a document `.get`?

I would like this to be as lightweight as possible, I know in advance the list of filenames we want to know about (they're favicons) so looping and doing .exists is less code, but perhaps slower than putting and pulling from the database.

Any information you have on the efficiency of db document requests and storage exists requests (which I would assume are doing something similar behind the scenes anyway).

Please ask for more information if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that Firestore clients try to maintain an open socket connection to the database, I'd give the edge to a database get being faster than checking for file existence in Cloud Storage.  With Firestore, you're less likely to pay the cost of establishing an SSL connection to the cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

From architectural point of view, I would save the file names in Firestore and retrieve them from the client directly based on the file name, its much simpler and you can add different types of images for different purposes without much thought down the road  under same bucket